# How to create testing.xml at run time from excel

Tags: selenium, testng

I wanted to generate testing.xml file at run time and for that I need to read test case name along with test data from excel file based on flag y/n and generate testng.xml

1. I am not getting how or is there any listener I can use to generate testng.xml so before actual execution I will have testng read. Or if I will write a code to create xml then what will be the right place to call that code
2. same test data and test case name I need to pass to @dataprovider

excel :
run | test case | username | password

Y   | abc1      | test1.   | pwd
N.  | abc2      | test2    | pwd

Comment: Why don’t you use cucumber with BDD. You can pass test-data in example table  and with help of tags you can run which ever test case you want to run

Comment: Thanks Sonali , but I have to use only testng and this will provide flexibility to control test case execution from excel. 
if I will go with cucumber then every time I need to update tags in runner class.